# Why does the combobox using the keyboard up & down arrows not reflect the textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, autocomplete, keydown, keyup

Why does the combobox using the keyboard up & down arrows not reflect the textbox in vb.net.

So I want the up and down arrows on the keyboard to still appear in the textbox

I use the String.Equals Method to check the value selected in the combox is correct or not by referring to the textbox.

Please Guide Me

Thanks

```
Public Class Form4
 Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = AutoSuggestList()
    End Sub
    Private Function AutoSuggestList() As AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim collection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Using connection As New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            collection.AddRange(connection.Query(Of String)("SELECT ColorCode FROM ColorCode").ToArray)
        End Using
        Return collection
    End Function
    Private Sub GetItemData(ByVal iditem As String)
        Dim item = COLORCODESERVICE.GetByColorcode2(iditem)
        If item IsNot Nothing Then
            If String.Equals(iditem, item.Colorcode, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                ComboBox1.Text = item.Colorcode
            End If
            TextBox1.Text = item.Colorname
            ComboBox1.Text = item.Colorcode
        Else
            MsgBox("Not Found Colorcode...")
            ComboBox1.ResetText()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            Return
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Up OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
            GetItemData(ComboBox1.Text)
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Back OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
            ComboBox1.ResetText()
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBox1_TextUpdate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.TextUpdate
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: RESULT ARROW UP & DOWN KEYBOARD]

Comment: How is this question different to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938735/why-do-i-have-to-press-escape-on-the-keyboard-twice-in-vb-net), other than being worded better? You seem to be asking the same question again, rather than editing the other question to make it better. Your new explanation is still inadequate though. You still haven't actually explained what you're trying to achieve. It honestly amazes me sometimes how bad so many people are at describing their problems. I've read both your questions and don't really understand why this code exists at all.

Comment: I should also point out that you also have failed to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in either question, which means that we can't test your code for ourselves and see the behaviour you're seeing. For one thing, your issue has absolutely nothing to do with databases so there should be no data access code in there. If you provide an example with a hard-coded list then we will be able to run that code ourselves, whereas we'd need your database to run the code you have posted. Etc.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `How is this question different to this one,` The post is different because this post asks about keeping the keyboard arrow up & down

Comment: @siwa86 what does that even mean? "...keeping the keyboard arrow up & down"?

Comment: @HardCode , 
So I want the up and down arrows on the keyboard to still appear in the textbox